# Received invalid SSL certificate from Cloud Foundry CLI V6

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to connect to my Cloud Foundry V2 instance through CF CLI V6 tool which I downloaded from https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli. It is giving me SSL certificate validation error on my Mac Book. Here are the details:

`cf api https://<IP Address>.xip.io
Setting api endpoint to https://api.<IP Address>.xip.io...
FAILED
Received invalid SSL certificate from api.<IP Address>.xip.io - not valid for the requested host`

I installed the same CLI tool on Windows 8 machine and it can connect to my Cloud Foundry Server without any issues and I was able to create Org. and Space. Not sure why this tool is doing this validation on Mac Book.

I also tried to run the command to skip the validation:

`cf api https://api.<IP Address>.xip.io --skip-ssl-validation`

but it gave me following error:

`Incorrect Usage.
NAME:
   api - Set or view target api url
USAGE:
   cf api [URL]`

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded the latest source code and build the cf executable form it. The following command is allowing me to connect:

`cf api https://api.<IP Address>.xip.io --skip-ssl-validation`

cheers,